# SQL - conditional ISNULL statement in a query

Tags: sql-server

I am using the following query to gather some information about each `ProductId` - note that a `ProductId` can contain several records in the `dbo.Sales` table:

```
SELECT 
c.ProductId, 
COUNT(*) as NumberOfRecords,
(SELECT
 (ISNULL(NULLIF(c.Text, ''), 'FALSE'))) as TextFieldHasData
FROM dbo.Sales c
JOIN dbo.Sources s 
ON c.ProductId = s.ProductId
AND s.SourceStatusId in (1,2)
GROUP BY c.ProductId, c.Status, s.SourceStatusId, c.Text
ORDER BY c.ProductId
```

I need to tweak the `ISNULL` part of the query, and I'm having trouble with the syntax; what I actually need to do is first check the `NumberofRecords`count - if the the `NumberofRecords` count for a given result record is greater than 1, then the `TextFieldHadData` field for that record should just say 'N/A'.  But, if the `NumberofRecords`count for a given result record = 1, then it should check whether the `c.Text` field is NULL or blank.  If it **is** NULL or Blank, the `TextFieldHasData` field would say 'FALSE.' If it is **not** NULL or blank, the TextFieldHasData field would say 'TRUE.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code, perhaps you are looking for something like the following (where you would be grouping up to ProductId level):

```
SELECT 
    c.ProductId
    , COUNT(*) as NumberOfRecords
    ,
        CASE
            WHEN COUNT(*) > 1
            THEN 'N/A'
            ELSE
                CASE
                    WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN ISNULL(c.Text, '') = '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) > 0
                    THEN 'TRUE'
                    ELSE 'FALSE'
                END
        END TextFieldHasData
FROM
    dbo.Sales c
    JOIN dbo.Sources s ON
        c.ProductId = s.ProductId
        AND s.SourceStatusId in (1, 2)
GROUP BY c.ProductId
ORDER BY c.ProductId
```

Comment: Hi Chris - yep it's your second suggestion.  I am definitely trying to group at the ProductId level.  Nicely done, thank you.  If you want to edit to delete the first suggestion, I'll mark it as the answer.  Unless you think it would be helpful to others to leave the first one in there for reference?

Comment: Nice job Chris.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the query:

I can not validate it as I don't have these tables, but it should work, unless you find a minor syntax error.

The idea is to use "**case when ...**" sql function

```
select v.productid,v.NumberOfRecords,
case
       when v.NumberOfRecords>1 then 'N/A'
       when v.NumberOfRecords=1 and isnull(v.TextFieldHasData,'') ='' then 'FALSE'
       else 'TRUE' end [textfieldhasdata]

 from(
SELECT 
c.ProductId, 
COUNT(*) as NumberOfRecords,
(SELECT
 (ISNULL(NULLIF(c.Text, ''), 'FALSE'))) as TextFieldHasData
FROM dbo.Sales c
JOIN dbo.Sources s 
ON c.ProductId = s.ProductId
AND s.SourceStatusId in (1,2)
GROUP BY c.ProductId, c.Status, s.SourceStatusId, c.Text) v
ORDER BY ProductId
```